# Bind JSON from API to multi select

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, html, drop-down-menu

So I am pulling questions for when a user registers on a web app from an API. I am trying to use Angular.js to do this by pulling questions that are separated by a key and a value as shown below into html select options. The API returns something like:

```
[
{
    "key": "1",
    "value": "What was the make and model of your first car?"
},
{
    "key": "2",
    "value": "In what city or town was your first job?"
},
{
    "key": "3",
    "value": "What is the name of your favorite childhood friend?"
}
]
```

There are 30 of these returned and I need to inject these into dropdowns.

Have been searching and trying and just not getting this with modifying my controller pointed to the right direction and revising my directives to allow this.

Not sure where I am going wrong, but hoping some of you can help or point me to a tutorial showing this very exact thing.

Thanks much.

Comment: Needed to add, that if a user selects a question in the uppermost dropdown, then that option wouldn't be available in the remaining dropdowns.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked out: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions ?

So in your markup you'd do: `<select ng-options="jsonValue.value as jsonValue in JsonValues" ng-model="selectedValue">`

And in your controller:

`$scope.jsonValues = // JSON result you posted above. Use route.resolve or whatever method to set this.`

When you change the dropdown value, `$scope.selectedValue` will update with the object `{ key : x, value : 'value' }`, corresponding to the selected value.

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply. So for the JSON returned by the API, I only see those if I run "http://localhost:8011/api/reg/questions" in Postman or Fiddler. Wouldn't think I would have to spit those back into my controller logic, but simply point and have some sort of repeat. Hope that makes sense as the idea is that the questions can be changed on the backend  and hten be reflected in the app.

Comment: Also, how would I deal with the issue where one questions selected in one dropdown does not show in the preceding 2 following dropdowns? You know how when you register, you normally select 3  questions and then input the answers for when a password reset is requested.

Comment: If your JSON is coming from an endpoint you need to call that endpoint from within your Angular controller to then setup the $scope object properly. For example `$http.get('localhost:8011/api/reg/questions').success(function(data) { $scope.questions = data.questions })` ngOptions **is** repeating code, when you set it on the `<select>` it generates